# Why isn't my acts as votable working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

When I click upvote I get an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feUEn.jpg)

Heres my routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #root 'pages#index'
  resources :posts

  devise_for :users
  # Define root URL
  root 'pages#index'

  # Define roots for pages
  get '/home' => 'pages#home'

  get '/user/:id' => 'pages#profile'

  get '/explore' => 'pages#explore'

  resources :posts do
    member do
      put "like", to: "posts#upvote"  # maybe change it to POSTS??
      put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote" # maybe change it to POSTS??
    end
  end
```

And my posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  #resources posts
  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    @post = current_user.posts.build(permit_post)
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Uploaded"
      redirect_to '/'
    else 
      flash[:error] = @posts_errors_full_messages
    end  
  end  

  def upvote
      current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
      current_user.upvotes @post
      redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.downvote_by current_user
  redirect_to :back
  end

  private 
    def permit_post
    params.require(:post).permit(:image, :title);
    end
end
```

And I have in my index

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :put, class: 'upvote' do %>
```

In the URL its showing myurl.com/posts/%23/like
I think this means its not getting the id, how can I fix it?
This is literally exhausting me, thanks in advance

EDIT:
I replaced @post with x since I was using a loop, that fixed the url but still getting the same error which is Couldn't find Post without an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the id of the post, since like is a member (child) of a post, the link should look like /posts/41/like

Next, you should remove the .exists? part from the controller.  That kind of thing only belongs in the model.

## Update

Your controller should look more like:

```
def upvote
  # current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) -- since you use devise, you don't need this
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  current_user.upvotes @post
  redirect_to :back
end
```

And your view link

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(@post), method: :put, class: 'upvote' do %>
```

Are you following a tutorial?  find_by_id is not suggested in Rails 4.  Did you create your own authentication or are you using a gem?

## update 2

It's not rails convention to use a singular name when referring to a collection (thus my assumption about your earlier link with @post).  So if you're trying to vote on your post index page, then your posts controller should be

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

And your view loop would be

```
<%= @posts.each do |post|
 <!-- Other view code here for what you want to display >
 <%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :put, class: 'upvote' do %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Still getting an error, yes i'm using devise gem and following a tutorial

Comment: hmm... you shouldn't see the url in the link.  Let me check on something

Comment: I created an app, added a user, used your link, your controller and your routes, and it's working fine.  Have you forgotten something like failed to restart your server after updating perhaps?

Comment: I restarted the server multiple times, when I pass @post it returns _Couldn't find Post with 'id'=#<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fed7024b610>_  and when I pass x for the loop it gets the id but I get _undefined method `upvotes' for #<User:0x007fed823b6358>_  and I appretiate the help

Comment: thanks a lot man, upvoted your answer but I have no reputations to make it show up, I replaced the def upvote code with code as the downvote.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  You should still be able to accept the answer.  Feel free to post a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: accepted, thanks, here's one if you would like to help http://stackoverflow.com/q/36607432/5738789

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue , and I tried `button_to` instead of `link_to`, it worked.