# Can I use Paperclip for comments in rails and how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, paperclip, acts-as-commentable

I want users to be able to comment on a post with an image or gif which Paperclip supports very well. How can i achieve that? Can it work with acts_as_commentable?

Comment: There isn't a straightforward way.  Any option will have to take several steps, are you using a style framework like bootstrap or foundation?

Comment: Yeah bootstrap but I want to style everything myself, the idea is can I implement both gems together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wysiwyg-rails](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails) it's easier

Comment: seems like too much of an effort for image implementation, do you know if the two gems can work together?